# PyQt5 Widgets not showing in MainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt5

Currently, I'm trying to display a Window with multiple widgets. 
However, when running the file, just a blank window is shown.

A majority of the code was generated using QtDesigner.

The code for my window is as follows:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMetaObject, QCoreApplication, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QFrame,  QLabel, QScrollBar, QPushButton
import sys

class MainWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        self.resize(800, 585)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.SetupUI()
        # setting calling method by button
        self.Colorize.clicked.connect(self.changeColor)
 
        # setting the default color of the button to light-grey
        self.Colorize.setStyleSheet("background-color : lightgrey")
 
        # Show all the widgets
        self.update()
        self.show()

    def SetupUI(self):
        #Drag Drop Frame
        self.dragDropFrame = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.dragDropFrame.setObjectName(u"dragDropFrame")
        self.dragDropFrame.setGeometry(QRect(30, 40, 741, 251))
        self.dragDropFrame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.dragDropFrame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.dragDropLabel = QLabel(self.dragDropFrame)
        self.dragDropLabel.setObjectName(u"dragDropLabel")
        self.dragDropLabel.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 681, 241))
        self.dragDropLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.scrollbar = QScrollBar(self.dragDropFrame)
        self.scrollbar.setObjectName(u"scrollbar")
        self.scrollbar.setGeometry(QRect(721, 0, 20, 251))
        self.scrollbar.setOrientation(Qt.Vertical)

        #Colorize Toggle Button
        self.Colorize = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Colorize.setObjectName(u"Colorize")
        self.Colorize.setGeometry(QRect(60, 320, 131, 131))
        self.Colorize.setCheckable(True)
        self.Colorize.setChecked(False)

        #Sharpen Toggle Button
        self.Sharpen = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Sharpen.setObjectName(u"Sharpen")
        self.Sharpen.setGeometry(QRect(340, 320, 131, 131))
        self.Sharpen.setCheckable(True)
        self.Sharpen.setChecked(False)

        #SuperRes Toggle Button
        self.SuperRes = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.SuperRes.setObjectName(u"SuperRes")
        self.SuperRes.setGeometry(QRect(620, 320, 131, 131))
        self.SuperRes.setCheckable(True)
        self.SuperRes.setChecked(False)

        #Compute Button
        self.Compute = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Compute.setObjectName(u"Compute")
        self.Compute.setGeometry(QRect(250, 500, 321, 61))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.Compute.setFont(font)

        self.retranslateUi()

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)
    
    def retranslateUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Image Restoration", None))
        self.Compute.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Compute", None))
        self.Colorize.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Colorize", None))
        self.Sharpen.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Sharpen", None))
        self.SuperRes.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Super Resolution", None))
        self.dragDropLabel.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Drag and Drop Images", None))

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        self.dragDropLabel.setHidden(True)
        files = [u.toLocalFile() for u in event.mimeData().urls()]
        for f in files:
            print(f)
    
    # method called by button
    def changeColor(self):
        if self.Colorize.isChecked():
            self.Colorize.setStyleSheet("background-color : lightblue")
        else:
            self.Colorize.setStyleSheet("background-color : lightgrey")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWidget()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am also getting the following errors when running the code, however I do not believe that these errors are the issue.

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Is there anything I'm missing for these widgets to show?

Comment: Creating a widget named `centralwidget` is insufficient, you must also *set* it as such (as the [documentation explains](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework)): `self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)`. Also: 1. do not try to merge pyuic generated code (if you're using Designer, follow the [official guidelines about it](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)), and always use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (even [in Designer](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html)). Finally, do not use capitalized names for object members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found the solution.

You named your central widget, but didn't set it.

You can put `self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)` after `self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")` and admire your beautiful Qt design.